# how to provide access key and other info while setting up cloudwatch using chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Hi am trying to create a chef recipe to install cloudwatch agents , i have something like this sample :

```
execute 'gexecutescripts' do
    command 'sudo python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region us-east-1'
    action :run
end
```

I get the below output:

```
Step 1 of 5: Installing pip ...DONE

Step 2 of 5: Downloading the latest CloudWatch Logs agent bits ... DONE

Step 3 of 5: Configuring AWS CLI ...
AWS Access Key ID [****************]:
Step 4 of 5: Configuring the CloudWatch Logs Agent ...
Path of log file to upload [/var/log/syslog]:
STDERR: EOF when reading a line
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./awslogs-agent-setup.py", line 1144, in <module>
    main()
  File "./awslogs-agent-setup.py", line 1140, in main
    setup.setup_artifacts()
  File "./awslogs-agent-setup.py", line 705, in setup_artifacts
    self.aws_logs_configure()
  File "./awslogs-agent-setup.py", line 805, in aws_logs_configure
    log_file_path = prompter.get_value(default_log_file_path, file_path_msg)
  File "./awslogs-agent-setup.py", line 986, in get_value
    response = input("%s [%s]: " % (prompt_text, current_value))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

How can i pass the access key , secret key and other values from my recipe?

Comment: use the [environment property](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html#properties) of the execute resource.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the access key to the config file is a bit troublesome to handle on the Chef recipe, so it is better to give the IAM role to the EC2 instance.

For details, refer to the following documents:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html